TypeScript: Progress Bar Timing Out and Pausing Unexpectedly
I'm implementing a progress bar in TypeScript using AJAX to fetch updates from the server. However, I'm encountering issues with the progress bar timing out and pausing unexpectedly.
class ProgressBarAlg {
  private _maxTry: number = 100;
  private _versuch: number = 0;
  private _timeOut: number = 500;

    public temp(res: string) {
        if (res != null) {
            if (res == "-1") {
                this.showHide(".el2block", false);
                if (this._lastUpdate == res) this._versuch++;
                if (this._versuch > this._maxTry) {
                    if (this._procTimeOut) clearTimeout(this._procTimeOut);
                    this.showHide(".el2block", false);
                    if (isEntwicklModeGlobal) {
                        console.log("timaout bei progressbar:" + this._versuch);
                        setValue("footer", "timaout bei progressbar:" + this._versuch);
                    }
                } else
                    this._procTimeOut = setTimeout(function () {
                        varProgressBarAlg.getProgressvalue(varProgressBarAlg.getflProz1());
                    }, 1000);
                this._lastUpdate = res;
                bodyDisabled(true);
                return;
            } else if (this._lastUpdate == "-1") {
                this.showHide(".el2block", true);
                this._lastUpdate = "";
            }
            if (res == this._lastUpdate) {
                this._versuch++;
            } else {
                let arr: Array<string> = res.split(SEPARATOR);
                let txt: string = "";
                let val: number = 0;
                if (arr.length > 1) {
                    txt = this._hideZahl ? "" : arr[0] + "/" + arr[1];
                    if (parseInt(arr[0]) > 0 && parseInt(arr[1]) > 0) val = (parseInt(arr[0]) * 1) / (1 * parseInt(arr[1]));
                    val = Math.abs(val * 100);
                    val.toFixed(0);
                }
                this._versuch = 0;
                this._lastUpdate = res;
                if (!isNaN(val) && val > 0 && val < 100) {
                    bodyDisabled(true, () => {
                        $JQ(".percentValue").html(val.toFixed(0) + "%");
                    });
                }
            }
            if (res == "-2") this._versuch = 0;
            if (this._versuch > this._maxTry) {
                if (this._procTimeOut) clearTimeout(this._procTimeOut);
                if (isEntwicklModeGlobal) {
                    console.error("timeout with progressbar:" + this._versuch);
                    setValue("footer", "timaout bei progressbar:" + this._versuch);
                }
            } else
                this._procTimeOut = setTimeout(function () {
                    varProgressBarAlg.getProgressvalue(varProgressBarAlg.getflProz1());
                }, this._timeOut);
        } else if (isEntwicklModeGlobal) console.log("res is null");
    }
}

The server responds with progress updates in the format: [current]!#![total]!#![phase_name]
The first two responses are 1!#!7!#!Phasen, then it jumps to 4!#!7!#!Phasen for the third and fourth responses.
I'm getting "timeout with progressbar" messages in the console.
